# How to show Shiny input of nodes and edges from visNetwork together instead of separate

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, visnetwork

I am building a network in Shiny using visNetwork package.

The function of showing nodes and edges input is interesting. However, nodes and edges input can only be shown separately instead of together in 1 box.

I followed the following instruction https://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/shiny.html to build the interactive nodes and edges input by hovering over the nodes and edges. 
This is done by using hoverNode/hoverEdge arg in visEvent function in visNetwork package. 
This is based on Shiny.OnInputChange function in javascript event

```
library(visNetwork)
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$network <- renderVisNetwork({
    # minimal example
    nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, label = 1:3)
    edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))

    visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
      visInteraction(hover = TRUE) %>%
      visEvents(hoverNode = "function(nodes) {
        Shiny.onInputChange('current_node_id', nodes);
      ;}"), hoverEdge = "function(edges) {
        Shiny.onInputChange('current_edge_id', edges);
      ;}")
  })

  output$shiny_return <- renderPrint({
    input$current_node_id
  })
}

  output$shiny_return <- renderPrint({
    input$current_edge_id
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  visNetworkOutput("network"),
  verbatimTextOutput("shiny_return")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Based on the code, I have 2 renderPrint output. I want to keep for 1, however, it is restricted by hoverNode/hoverEdge arguments .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Shiny.onInputChange` allows us to specify any name for the output. Since at any given time you can hover over either a node or an edge you can simply give both the nodes and edges the same name in the JS code, and refer to this input on the Shiny server-side code. This is what it would look like:

```
library(visNetwork)
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$network <- renderVisNetwork({
    # minimal example
    nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, label = 1:3)
    edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))

    visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
      visInteraction(hover = TRUE) %>%
      visEvents(hoverNode = "function(nodes) {
                Shiny.onInputChange('unique_id', nodes);
                ;}", hoverEdge = "function(edges) {
    Shiny.onInputChange('unique_id', edges);
    ;}")
  })

  output$shiny_return <- renderPrint({
    input$unique_id
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  visNetworkOutput("network"),
  verbatimTextOutput("shiny_return")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```